# Custom View not displaying completely in activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-custom-view

I'm trying to display "Spaces-Navigation-View" from here https://github.com/armcha/Space-Navigation-View

The problem I'm facing is that the view appears perfectly in simple activity but not in my main activity which contains coordinator layout.

Here is the xml for my main activity and the result is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
android:id="@+id/main_content"

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"                                                 
android:layout_width="match_parent"                                                 
android:layout_height="match_parent"                                                 
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"                                                  
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"                                                 
tools:context="com.rvnd.bookshare.Strt">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/transparent"

        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <TextView
            android:text="Book Share"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:textSize="27sp"
            android:textColor="@color/text"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabGravity="fill"

 app:tabTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.TabWidget"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:background="#FFD54F"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="Syncing..."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>



<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:space_background_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"



 app:layout_behavior="com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationViewBehavior"/>

        />
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/booky"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the result of it 
[image]

On the other hand, if I use the same view in a different simpler activity, the view is rendered properly

Here is the code and below it, is how it should actually look like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout


 android:id="@+id/activity_history"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.rvnd.bookshare.History"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/skyblue"

    android:layout_height="40dp">


<TextView
    android:text="All your book transfers are recorded here..."
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textSize="13sp"/>

    <Button
        android:text="Clear history"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:textAllCaps="false"

        android:layout_width="98dp"
        android:textSize="12sp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rec"/>


<com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:space_background_color="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"



app:layout_behavior="com.luseen.spacenavigation.SpaceNavigationViewBehavior"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Here is the result :
[image]

I've tried everything and It just doesnt display properly, please do help!
Thanks

Comment: remove your floatingbutton code

Comment: That didn't work either :\